# Why do we use Slice int in golang

Tags: go

In the below **program** what can we call this - ***type Sequence [ ]int***

I am unable to understand whether it's a sliced structure or anything else..

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Sequence []int 

type Stats interface {
    GreaterThan(x int) Sequence
}

func (s Sequence) GreaterThan(x int) (ans Sequence) {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v > x {
            ans = append(ans, v)
        }
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    s := Sequence{5, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8}
    fmt.Println("", s.GreaterThan(2))
}
```

Comment: `Sequence` is a slice of ints. Perhaps more generally you could say it's a slice type. But the terms "Sliced structure" and "Structured Slice" are both incorrect.

Comment: What does "sliced structure" mean? It's a slice of `int`.

Comment: Technically, `Sequence` is a *named type* with *underlying type* of `[]int`. `Sequence` is a slice of ints, and you can define methods for the type `Sequence`. A `Sequence` is assignable to `Sequence` values, or values of the unnamed type `[]int`

Answer (score -1):

Sequence is array of int
and s is slice from Sequence filled

Comment: Sequence is a slice, not an array.

Comment: @SHASHANK  The declared type is required to add the method shown in your question.